# How to use KeepScale component in react-zoom-pan-pinch library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on a React component for a prototype using the react-zoom-pan-pinch library as mentioned in the title.

What I currently have is a box with different tags inside of it that you can zoom in and out on using two buttons or your mouse.
You can see it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-pare-20pcp5?file=/src/components/showcase.tsx

So far, so good.
However, what I would like to achieve is more like this example from their documentation:
https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/examples-keep-scale--keep-scale

As you can see, the size of these pins in the above example always stays the same but the distance between them increases/decreases as you zoom into/out of the box. Unfortunately, there is no code example anywhere on how to do this with the KeepScale component and I've been struggling trying to replicate it. I'm running out of ideas at this point and maybe someone of here knows how this could be done or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I was so blind but there was already a hint on how to do this here:
https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/267

I added the onTransformed prop to my TransformWrapper and handle any changes using an event handler:

```
onTransformed={(e) => handleScaleChange(e)}
```

In this function I now have access to the current scale value using the transformState property and can update my state:

```
function handleScaleChange(event: shape) {
    setScale(event.instance.transformState.scale);
}
```

Using CSS transform property I can now scale my element:

```
transform: `scale(${1 / scale})`
```

Now it works like I wanted it to!
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-pare-20pcp5?file=/src/components/showcase.tsx

Like I mentioned in my question, there is also a KeepScale component available, I am however not quite sure how to achieve that same effect using it. For now, this will do.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the examples used in the documentation of `react-zoom-pan-pinch` is available on [Github in the `stories` folder](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/tree/master/src/stories/examples). In your case, the code for the `keep-scale` component can be found [here](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/blob/master/src/stories/examples/keep-scale/example.tsx).

## How to use `KeepScale` component

> The following explanation is for version 3.0.7 of react-zoom-pan-pinch.

The `KeepScale` component is imported as follows:

```js
import { KeepScale } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
```

If you have a component `Pin` inside a `TransformComponent` and you want `Pin` to maintain its scale when zooming occurs, then:

1. Wrap `Pin` with `KeepScale`.
2. Wrap `KeepScale` with a `div`.
3. **All styles related to the positioning of the `Pin` should be transferred to the `div` wrapping `KeepScale`.**

```js
<div
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    zIndex: 2,
    marginLeft: "-200px",
  }}
>
  <KeepScale>
    <Pin fill="red" style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px" }} />
  </KeepScale>
</div>
```

Trying to put the positioning styles directly on the `Pin` did **not** work for me:

```js
<KeepScale>
  <Pin
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: "50%",
      left: "50%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
      zIndex: 2,
      marginLeft: "-200px",
    }}
    fill="red"
    style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px" }}
  />
</KeepScale>
```

## Example

I have modified your code to use `KeepScale`. The codesandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mccarthy-njzg7s?file=/src/components/showcase.tsx). The main modification occurred here:

```js
                            {tags.map((tag) => (
                              <div
                                style={{
                                  position: "absolute",
                                  left: `${tag.x}px`,
                                  top: `${tag.y}px`
                                }}
                              >
                                <KeepScale>
                                  {" "}
                                  <div
                                    className={"technology-tag"}
                                    onClick={() => console.log(tag.label)}
                                    key={tag.id}
                                    style={{
                                      backgroundColor: tag.color,
                                      borderRadius: "13px",
                                      color: "white",
                                      fontSize: "12px",
                                      padding: "5px"
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    {tag.label}
                                  </div>
                                </KeepScale>
                              </div>
                            ))}
```